How to override the default click action behavior on a field within a tree view when adding a new record
This field is "lot_id" (for serialization) in the tree view of inventory adjustment.   We need to generate our own serialized number and thus not want the user to type in their own.
The current behavior with Odoo17 when doing inventory adjustment is that the newly added record would have this field empty; it is only when the user clicked into it, then it would give a selection of existing lot number, and then only if the user start typing, it will show the "create..." and "create and edit..." menus.  These are not desired

Since it is a new record, we shouldn't use existing lot_ids; so we don't need the initial selections.
I do not want the user to type in anything since that would be used instead of our customized serialized name.

With our previous installation of Odoo12, we only need to define the "no_quit_create" option and that would have prevented the selection to come up and would only have "create and edit..." menu when user click inside the field; but that doesn't work the same here in 17.
I have 2 options here:

Automatically generated and set the new lot_id for this new record.   It wouldn't be save with the record (stock_quant) until the record is actually saved.   I can afford to waste the lot_id if it is not save; and in that case, I can make this field "readonly" in the treeview?
Override the behavior inside the field so that it will not show the selection, it will not allow the user to type in the field, and it will just let the user to choose "create and edit..." option which would open up my lot form view (which would default to use our custom serialization code).

So far, I weren't able to find informations on neither approaches.   Can someone shared examples or documentations that would help me?
With the first approach of default, I found something that might be related using api.onchange which I tried like this:
_inherit = 'stock.quant'

@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_inventory(self):
   if (self.tracking in ["lot", "serial"] and not self.lot_id):
      self.lot_id = self.env["stock.lot"]._generate_serial_number()

With the second approach, I hadn't been able to find anything yet.
